# How to extract texts from elements selected by class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a website using `BeautifulSoup`.

The website data reads:

```
<div content-43 class="item-name">This is the text I want to grab</div>
```

I am currently using:

```
 item_store = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"item-name"})
```

However it returns the entire line of HTML like the div tags instead of just the text I want.

Comment: try `soup.select("div.item-name")`, css selector are much more flexible than `find_all`

Comment: If you would confirm the url you are trying to scrape, you'd receive better responses

Comment: Based on my experience each library parsing DOM elements have some kind of a method returning only content. Try checking what type of object is being returned and check the methods of that class. Obviously if it's str, you're using wrong function :)

Comment: Try: "soup.find('div', class_='item-name').text"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract texts and not the element - be aware that if you have to iterate the `ResultSet` of `find_all()` before you can call the methode.

With `find()` on a single element:

```
soup.find("div",{"class":"item-name"}).get_text()
```

With `find_all()` on a `ResultSet`:

```
[e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"item-name"})]
```

While using `select()` and [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) also on a `ResultSet`:

```
[e.get_text() for e in soup.select('div.item-name')]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div content-43 class="item-name">This is the text I grab with find() and also with find_all()</div>
<div content-43 class="item-name">This is the text I want to grab with find_all() </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find("div",{"class":"item-name"}).get_text())
print([e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"item-name"})])
```

##### Output

```
This is the text I grab with find() and also with find_all()
```

and

```
['This is the text I grab with find() and also with find_all()',
 'This is the text I want to grab with find_all() ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.get_text()` methood or `text` property 
you can print them like this

```
for item in item_store:
    print(item.text)
    # print(item.get_text())
```